# Prolog - How can I return a list where each element appears only once?

Tags: list, prolog, logic, unification

I have a predicate set/2 that is supposed to instantiate the second argument to a list whose elements are only one occurance of each term from the first argument. What I have so far is:

```
set([],OutList).
set([X|InList],OutList) :- \+member(X,InList), append([X], OutList, OutListNew), set(InList,OutListNew).                      
set([X|InList],OutList) :- member(X,InList), set(InList,OutList).
```

And calling set/2:

```
set([1,1,2,3],X).
```

returns true. That's halfway there - I want X to be instantiated to [1,2,3] - but I'm not sure how to make X true in this case. Any help and explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Prolog should warn you have a **singleton** in the first clause, that is

```
set([],OutList).
```

It means that when the execution hits such clause, it **succeeds**, but `OutList` remains unbound.

Now should be clear that you need to substitute `OutList` with the empty list.

Another bug is located in the second clause.

`append([X], OutList, OutListNew)` should be instead `append([X], OutListNew, OutList)`. As a style note, it can be substituted by this unification: `[X|OutListNew]=OutList`, and then moved into the head.

Comment: I give up; what should OutList be bound to?

Comment: See the last version, I have substituted (clarified) my hint, and solved another more substantial bug.

Comment: Seriously, thank you. Two hours of pouring over traces only got me so far. Now I can sleep!

Answer (score 0):

sort/2 removes duplicates (msort/2 leaves duplicates, if that's what you want.

Also: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=list_to_set/2

Comment: Thanks! But I'm supposed to write my own functions that do this; I'm trying to learn prolog. Working through the exercises in Learn Prolog Now.

Comment: Please only link to external sites when you've included all of the relevant detail in the answer itself. Links should support your answer only.